# In SwiftUI, how to iterate over array that is and attribute of a custom object

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a simple object model with two attributes, the second attribute is actually an array of Strings. in a simple view, I want to show the first attribute which is roleName and below it iterate over the second attribute to show them in a list or using forEach loop. I tested it with an independent array of Strings it works, but this way the actions don't show up. thanks for the help. Code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ActionsView: View {

var role = Role(roleName: "Witch", roleActions: ["Action 1","Action 2"])

var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 20) {

           Text(role.roleName)
                    .font(.title).fontWeight(.heavy)

           VStack() {
                Text("Choose Your Actions")
                .font(.headline)

           List(role.roleActions, id: \.self) { action in
                HStack {
                    Text(action)
                }
            }


            }
        }

    }
}


struct ActionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ActionsView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Role : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString

    var roleName: String
    var roleActions: [String]
}

struct RowView : View {

    var role : Role

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            HStack {
                ForEach(role.roleActions, id: \.self) { action in
                    Text(action)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var roles = [Role(roleName: "Witch", roleActions: ["Action 1","Action 2"]),
                 Role(roleName: "Hero", roleActions: ["Action 3", "Action4"])]

    var body: some View {

        List (roles, id: \.self) { role in
            Text(role.roleName)
                .font(.title).fontWeight(.heavy)

            VStack() {
                Text("Choose Your Actions")
                    .font(.headline)

                RowView(role: role)

            }
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 140)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris, It worked very well. I just want to know the mechanics behind your code, the only difference between yours and mine I think is only the fact that you refactored the role into a separate view, I was looping in the roles actions indeed, the build and run but it doesn’t show what is supposed to show. Thanks again.